# How to delete strings which contain random characters by regex syntax

Tags: mysql, regex, replace, notepad++, sublimetext2

I have a text file (.sql database) which containings these strings

```
[center:t1jrwz84]
[center:18gl5k7g]
[center:3tkgm3zz]
[center:1jrwz84d]
```

They appear in text file like this

```
Hello [center:t1jrwz84] everyone. How are[center:18gl5k7g]you today?
Glad to meet[center:3tkgm3zz] you. Thanks for[center:1jrwz84d] coming.
```

How to delete all strings by replace function of Editor Notepad++, Sublime, ... with regex syntax?

I try this regex syntax in Notepad++

```
- Find what: [[center].*.[]]
- Replace with:
```

And this is the result

```
Hyou today?
Glad  coming.
```

Of course this is wrong. It isn't my target. My target is

```
Hello everyone. How are you today?
Glad to meet you. Thanks for coming.
```

PS: I want to delete theme because these are wrong bbcodes, html tags in the posts of smf forum database. I converted it from phpbb (center, right, justify, font, ...) with custom bbcode and Almsamim WYSIWYG Editor. MySQL doesn't support regex syntax in replace query, UDF addon is so complicated, so i have to do it with .sql file and Text Editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) capture; the `.*` needs to be qualified with a `?` to keep from swallowing everything up to the last ']' on the line.

Find: `\[center\:(.*?)\]`

and replace with nothing. Here I've also removed extraneous brackets and escaped the '[', ']', and ':' with backslashes.